# is there anyway to Generate G-Code from STL file

Tags: cad, g-code, cnc

I am working on a project to generate G-Code for 3D Model in STL Format.

Suggest me how I can do it

Basically this generated G-Code will be used with Milling CNC.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you want something affordable I would suggest [fusion360](https://www.autodesk.com/products/fusion-360/personal), however there are a ton of options out there.  Your decision should be made based on the complexity of your project and type of CNC machine you have.  Almost all of the modern CAD/CAM packages will handle STL files as well as STEP and many other formats.  You also need a post processor to handle the formatting of your NC files since all machines do not have the same format requirements as well as having proprietary G-code, M-code and other functions.

Answer (score 1):

You need [CAM Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_manufacturing), a program that has an algorithm that extracts the path of the STL drawing and based in the type of your machine, generate the correct CNC commands.

There are several proprietary programs for this on the market and it really depends on your machine type and tools. Maybe [this link](https://www.instructables.com/TinkerCad-and-Fusion-360-to-CNC-Router-a-3D-Pictur/) will help you get some ideas.

If you want to develop your own CAM, I warn you that this is not a trivial job...